# October CMS: Custom Plugin - Reference to current RainLab.Blog Post from component

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am brand new to developing a custom October CMS plugin and I'm working on a plugin to extend RainLab.Blog where I can't seem to reference the current single post from my plugin's component when visiting an article.

Assuming I'm reading a blog post at **[www.example.com/:slug](http://www.example.com/:slug)**, I want to query my plugin's custom table where one of it's columns is a foreign key to RainLab.Blog's post, called "**post_id**".

When inspecting the table in PHP My Admin, I can see that the ID in column **post_id** is indeed the corresponding post ID for the correct post, but I know of no way to fetch the correct row using this ID.

I'm currently hardcoding the post ID to get, just to have *something* for the front end, like so:

```
return Business::where('post_id', 4) -> first();
```

This ofcourse refers to the 4th post no matter which post I'm reading.
I can't seem to figure out how I'd go about targeting the "current" post. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! After some tinkering, I replaced:

```
return Business::where('post_id', 4) -> first();
```

With this correction:

```
if ($this -> page['post'])  {
    return Business::where('post_id', $this -> page['post'] -> getAttribute('id')) -> first();
}
```